File descriptors 3-5 in linux
I'm doing an university project where storing files in an array of pointers indexed by their file descriptors is required. I know file descriptors 0 to 2 are stdin, stdout and stderr respectively but i do not know what file descriptors 3-5 are named.

What's so special about those descriptors to give them a name?

I have to store them inside a list that is later printed. This list has to contain the filename that corresponds to the FD. newly opened files through my project ( a shell ) can easily be added and 0-2 are stdin, stdout and stderr. however i have no idea about FD 3-5

What makes you think, they even exist?

For future reference, if you want to know what fd N refers to on Linux, just look at /proc/PID/fd/N for process id "PID"

Only 3 - 0,1,2 have default values and meaning

0: STDIN (standard input)
1: STDOUT (standard output)
2: STDERR (standard error)

When you open the file you will get the next available - for example 3.
Example:
xx:~$ ls -og /proc/self/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 0 Sep 24 09:05 0 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ 1 0 Sep 24 09:05 1 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ 1 0 Sep 24 09:05 2 -> /dev/tty1
lr-x------ 1 0 Sep 24 09:05 3 -> /proc/75/fd

you will see that ls opens the file and it is assigned descriptor 3

ONLY 0~2 are predefined.
3 and above are provided to users.
It depends on your open() order.
So, the number COULD be NOT EXIST .
You had better open() a file and get the number by yourself.
Even the FD=3 is exist currently!
If it's NOT open by yourself, it might BE CLOSED by other program any time.
Ref:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams

fopen does not provide the file descriptor, in contrast to open. There are more functions that can return a file descriptor, e.g. dup, socket, ...

@Bodo Function fileno(stream) returns the file descriptor of a stream, that is opened by fopen().

@Bodo you are right. too long to call (f)open function. thanks

Nevermind people it was just my terminal emulator being extremely stupid and assigning tty and pipe streams to FD 3-5. This has happened with alacritty and wayland jic anyone has the same problem. Sorry for stupid question :)

Re "anyone has the same problem", What problem?

Yes, it is possible for more file descriptors than 0 - 2 to already be open when your program initially enters main().  You can even produce that effect yourself for child processes that you launch.  But there is no pre-defined significance to such additional file descriptor numbers.  Also, it is not safe to assume that all pre-opened file descriptor numbers form a contiguous block.
